# UICollectionView displays only first item from dataset

Tags: ios, core-data, uicollectionview

There are two entities (**Department** <-->> **Employee**).

There are 4 employees in this department. When I fetch all Employees in this Department my log window show:

**CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0017s for 4 rows.**

everything well.

But `UICollectionView` displays only first employee for 4 times.
For example:

**Employee1, Employee1, Employee1, Employee1**

instead of

**Employee1, Employee2, Employee3, Employee4**

I thing there is some mistake in **cellForItemAtIndexPath**:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellRecipe";    
    collectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Employee *emp = [array_ objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    cell.name.text = emp.name;
    cell.image.image = emp.thumbImg;

    return cell;
}
```

**array_** is a **NSMutableArray** after fetch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is in the indexing method try this code.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return  noOfItem/ noOfSection;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return noOfSection;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellRecipe";    
     collectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
  ;

    Employee *emp = [array_ objectAtIndex:indexPath.section * noOfSection + indexPath.row];
    cell.name.text = emp.name;
    cell.image.image = emp.thumbImg;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: FIXED! mistake was in **numberOfItemsInSection** and **numberOfSectionsInCollectionView** )